# How can I update a date field with a formula result?

Tags: workflow, validation-rule, time-dependent-workflow

I have the following formula: `Close_Date__c  + 20`

And I want update the `Hire_By__c` field when after 20 days of Close_Date__c, but I get the following error:

> Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Date)

What can I do?

Comment: You should read 'How to write a good question': https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Robs You can type `[ask]` as a quick link to that page, it looks like [ask].

Comment: @sfdcfox what other short cuts are there?

Comment: @Robs I don't know all of them, but the ones I use most are `[ask]` ([ask]), `[help]` ([help]), `[tour]` ([tour]), and `[tag:something]` (e.g. [tag:workflow]).

Comment: @Robs There's also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for *that* link. I've been looking for it for ages.

Answer (score 3):

Validation rules cannot update data. As the name would imply, a validation rule simply validates data.

The result of a formula for a validation rule must always be a boolean, as indicated by the error message you're getting.

Instead, you should use a workflow rule with a field update action, process builder, a flow, or an apex trigger.